# Swagger Api doc with generics

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I use Swashbuckle (5.2.2) and Swagger to create a documentation of my WebAPI project.
I need to create a static documentation so I use swagger2markup on the json generated and this works fine.

However, I have a lot of generic types in my API for paging, for resources, etc.
Many return types looks like that: `Page<Resource<MyType>>`

As a result, in the documentation I get a lot (**A LOT**) of redundant definitions. For each `Page<Resource<MyType>>`, I get 3 definitions, if I have 10 types, I get 30 definitions (instead of 13), if I have 100 types, I get 300 definitions (instead of 103).

Is there a way to reduce this excess of information gracefully ?